# SQL: select date rows that contain specific hour and minute

Tags: sql, date, select

I am querying a table that has the date column as follows:

```
date
2021-03-08 05:05:31+00
2021-03-08 05:10:31+00
```

How can I select all the rows that contain 05:05 as the hour and minute in SQL? i.e. rows where hour = 05, and minute = 05. In this case it will be the first row.

Comment: what's your dbms? MySQL <> postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: How can I select all the rows that contain 05:05 as the hour and minute in SQL?

A: For MySQL, look in the [MySql Date and Time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html).  There, you'll find [Extract()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract).

You can use it as follows:

> https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_extract.asp
>
> Extract the minute from a datetime:
>
> ```
> SELECT EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM "2017-06-15 09:34:21");
> ```

This assumes that you're storing the column as a "Date" type.

Different RDBMS vendors have different Date/Time functions.  You'll have to read the documentation and experiment to determine which syntax to use for your particular DB vendor and your particular table schema.

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Use below Query for get Result as per your question .**

There is **DateName** function in **SQL** and you can put this in your query as below.

CreatedDate is column name..
**Example :**

```
Select * from #tmp1 where datename(hour,createdDate)=07 And datename(minute,CreatedDate)=07
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but think DATENAME() is MSSQL-specific.